# Max instances of QAudioOutput?

Tags: qt

I need to develop an application which must reproduce many different sounds in parallel, each adjustable with its own volume level. Using an instance of QAudioOutput for each sound it can be done quite easily but there is a limit regarding how many instances of QAudioOutput can be allocated? I didn't find any information about this in the Qt documentation page.

Comment: It seems that https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodeviceinfo.html#availableDevices, gives you the number of available audio devices for a given `QAudio::Mode`, on your system.

Comment: In my understanding this call return only the available physical devices in the system, not how many output channels each devices can support.